# PSCP.PSSH command to copy files to remote server

Tags: linux

How can I use pscp.pssh command to copy files to the remote server with the help of private key and not password.

This is the command I am using and I get password prompt. Please help

```
pscp.pssh -h hosts.txt -l vipin -x "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i vipin_rsa.pem" -Av example.txt /tmp/
```

Some of the answers to the questions:

- The remote servers have public key.
- I get a password prompt while running the command.
- Private key resides in the same directory from where I am executing the command.

Comment: I'd start reading the the `man` page (or other documentation) of whatever that tool is

Comment: Do you have your public key on other servers? Do you get a password, or a passphrase prompt? Are you executing this in the directory where the private key resides? Your question is lacking a lot of required detail.

Comment: @Panki I think you got some problem reading the question. the command simply shows the private key path. If you are wondering I didn't read man page and came directly posting the question, you are wrong. So please don't try and act smart please on public forum.

Comment: I don't see a path anywhere, only the filename `vipin_rsa.pem`. Ok, I won't "act smart" and try to help you any longer

Comment: Yes that means it's in same path from where I ran the command

Comment: @Panki To answer your questions
- Yes, the remote servers have public key
- I get password and not Passpharse prompt
- Private key resides in the same directory from where I am executing the command

I hope now it's clear. Let me know if you still need more info to answer this question.
Thanks

Comment: @vipinkumar you've already lost one person who's trying to help you. Please update your question to provide the exatra information. If you leave it in the comments it's harder for others to find and that makes it harder for people to answer your question. You need to answer the questions that have been asked, because without those answers we'd only be guessing. «  Do you have your public key on other servers? Do you get a password, or a passphrase prompt? Are you executing this in the directory where the private key resides? »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `pscp.pssh` is [the parallel SCP tool from this project.](https://github.com/lilydjwg/pssh) Its man page can be found [here.](https://www.mankier.com/1/pscp.pssh)

> -A
> --askpass
>
> Prompt for a password and pass it to ssh.  The password may be used for either to unlock a key or for password authentication. The password is transferred in a fairly secure manner (e.g., it will not show up in argument lists).  However, be aware that a root user on your system could potentially intercept the password.

In other words, `pscp.pssh` is asking for a password **because you have told it to ask**, by using the option `-A`. If you don't want that, remove the option, i.e. change the `-Av` to just `-v` in your command line.

If you still get a password prompt after that, you will have to figure out which of the (potentially) many hosts in your `hosts.txt` file is rejecting the key authentication, and **read the logs of that remote server** to find out why its `sshd` is rejecting your key.

A common reason is incorrect permissions to the authorized keys file on the remote server: if other users (other than root) could write their keys to the file, `sshd` will assume the authorized keys file may have been tampered with, and ignores it entirely. If this is the case, the log message from `sshd` in the server's log will describe exactly which file or directory has the incorrect permissions - but won't pass that information to an as-yet-unauthenticated (= not yet proven to be legitimate!) client for security reasons.